# TypeError: "Cannot read property 'questions' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm finishing debugging an App I've built for a React-Redux course I'm doing. And in the App, I'm supposed to add questions in a form just like the following:

[image: Add Screen]

But, when I click submit, it returns to me an error, just like the following:

[image: Error]

I'd build and simulated the App here in codesandbox: https://sit9d.csb.app/login

The app runs properly at the point when I decide to add a question, then suddenly it pops up the error showed.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you showed basically tells you the problem,

`Cannot read property 'questions' of undefined`

in this line of code:

`users[authedUser].questions`

It means that `users[authedUser]` is undefined, so you have failed to check whether you have a valid authedUser that is in your `users` object